# Modify msg.data

Tags: encoding, byte, solidity, fallback

Is it possible to modify `msg.data` by assigning a new value to it and forwarding it to the next function call?

For example:

`Proxy.sol`

```js
fallback() external payable virtual {
        _fallback();
}

function _fallback() internal virtual {
        _beforeFallback();
        _delegate(_implementation());
}
```

Can you do something in `_beforeFallback` that changes `msg.data` and passes it `_delegate`? Like:

```js
_beforeFallback() internal override {
         msg.data = msg.data + 0x1111000000000000000000000000000000001111 //random example
}
```

Thanks!